# dispatch_group_notify is called before all tasks are done

Tags: ios, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I'm struggling with `dispatch_group` and `dispatch_group_notify`, which is called before all tasks are finished. What I am trying to do it iterate over a number of queries, fetch them, and process the returned XML into CoreData entities. Then when everything is completed, I call save on the context to save all data to the store. But `dispatch_group_notify` is called before all tasks have completed, and nothing is saved.

Here is some code:

```
dispatch_group_t dispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create();

for (NSString *query in queryArray)
{
    dispatch_group_enter(dispatchGroup);
    NSLog(@"enter");

    [myDownloadClient searchForQuery: query
                      withParameters: nil
                          completion: ^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                             [self processXML: data];
                             NSLog(@"end import");
    }];

    NSLog(@"leave");
    dispatch_group_leave(dispatchGroup);
}

dispatch_group_notify(dispatchGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    NSLog(@"save");
    [self saveContext];
}
```

What I see in the log is

```
enter
leave
enter
leave
...
save
end import
...
```

As you can see save is displayed before all the downloading and XML processing is done, so there is nothing to save.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `[myDownloadClient searchForQuery:query ...]` is an asynchronous method. Calling `dispatch_group_leave` after the call to `[myDownloadClient searchForQuery:query ...]` doesn't really do anything; you're basically entering the group and then immediately leaving it. Instead, you need to call `dispatch_group_leave` after `[self processXML:data]` inside `searchForQuery:...`'s completion block:

```
for (NSString *query in queryArray)
{
    dispatch_group_enter(dispatchGroup);
    NSLog(@"enter");

    [myDownloadClient searchForQuery: query
                      withParameters: nil
                          completion: ^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                              [self processXML: data];
                              NSLog(@"end import");

                              NSLog(@"leave");
                              dispatch_group_leave(dispatchGroup);
                          }
    }];

}
```

That way, you don't leave the group until after the search and processing are complete.

Answer (score 1):

While you're calling your for-loop, it will not process its bottom code. until then. However those fetching was in a code block. Those block are waiting for the returns, while you continue to process the bottom code after the for loop. since the save was a bit faster to process, it will keep being the first on the line before those fetching block is done.